# howto get fit parameters from seaborn distplot fit=?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using seaborn distplot (data, fit=stats.gamma)

How do I get the fit parameters returned?

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
df = pd.read_csv ('RequestSize.csv')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
reqs = df['12 web pages']
reqs = reqs.dropna()
reqs = reqs[np.logical_and (reqs > np.percentile (reqs, 0), reqs < np.percentile (reqs, 95))]
dist = sns.distplot (reqs, fit=stats.gamma)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the object you passed to `distplot`:

```
stats.gamma.fit(reqs)
```

Answer (score 7):

I confirm the above is true - the sns.distplot fit method is equivalent to the fit method in scipy.stats so you can get the parameters from there, e.g.:

```
from scipy import stats

ax = sns.distplot(e_t_hat, bins=20, kde=False, fit=stats.norm);
plt.title('Distribution of Cointegrating Spread for Brent and Gasoil')

# Get the fitted parameters used by sns
(mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(e_t_hat)
print "mu={0}, sigma={1}".format(mu, sigma)

# Legend and labels 
plt.legend(["normal dist. fit ($\mu=${0:.2g}, $\sigma=${1:.2f})".format(mu, sigma)])
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

# Cross-check this is indeed the case - should be overlaid over black curve
x_dummy = np.linspace(stats.norm.ppf(0.01), stats.norm.ppf(0.99), 100)
ax.plot(x_dummy, stats.norm.pdf(x_dummy, mu, sigma))
plt.legend(["normal dist. fit ($\mu=${0:.2g}, $\sigma=${1:.2f})".format(mu, sigma),
           "cross-check"])
```

[image]

Comment: this is for a normal distribution. OP is using gamma. Do you know how to interpret the three values that are returned for stats.gamma.fit()?

Comment: @ChrisJ.Vargo :  shape, loc, scale = stats.gamma.fit(data)